# How to put a breakpoint to after last line of a loop in GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, breakpoint

Consider the following loop:

```c
28:  while (true) {
29:    chThdSleepMilliseconds(1);
30:    txbuffer[1] = num_zero + offset;
31:    spiExchange(&SPID1, 2, txbuffer, rxbuffer);
32:    // we want to examine rxbuffer at this point 
33:  }
```

I want to examine contents of `rxbuffer` in GDB after `spiExchange` function is executed. The following doesn't work:

```
(gdb) break main.c:32
(gdb) continue
```

GDB doesn't hit above breakpoint (probably as expected). If I put a breakpoint `main.c:31` and then execute `next`, context is totally changed, so there is no `rxbuffer` at that point.

Currently I insert an unused variable and put a breakpoint at that point:

```c
31:    spiExchange(&SPID1, 2, txbuffer, rxbuffer);
32:    int x; // we want to examine rxbuffer at this point 
33:  }
```

How can I put a breakpoint at that point *without defining the temporary variable*?

Comment: have you tried line 33?

Comment: Yes, I did now. No hit occurred at that one either.

Comment: I don't think you can break on a line without code, which means line 32 and 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your breakpoint at line 29. That's the statement that will be executed after line 31, and the breakpoint will break **before** line 29 is executed. The only disadvantage is that you will break one extra time, before line 31 is executed the first time.

Answer (score 1):

My current approach as a global¹ and extandable² solution is declaring a `NOOP` and placing breakpoint at that line:

```c
5: #define NOOP ({;})
...
31:    spiExchange(&SPID1, 2, txbuffer, rxbuffer);
32:    NOOP; // put a breakpoint at this point
33:  }
...
```

```
(gdb) break main.c:32
```

The `NOOP` macro will be removed by optimization, so optimization shouln't be used in order this approach to work.

> ¹: "Global" means this approach is not tailored to be applied to a loop but can also be applied to after last line of an `if` or a `switch` statement.
>
> ²: "Extandable" means you may add code after `line 31` that might change `rxbuffer` contents. With this approach you don't have to relocate your breakpoint in such cases.

## Edit

If `#define NOOP ({;})` does not work for you for some reason, you may change `NOOP` definition temporarily by whatever works for you, eg:

```c
//#define NOOP ({;})
#define NOOP chThdYield()
#define NOOP someSleepFunction(0)
```